# How to arrange the two divs vertically with a space between them?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <div>TOP</div>
  <div>BOTTOM</div>
</div>
```

TOP and BOTTOM should be centered and I'd like to have an arbitrary space margin between them. I've seen many answers in SO suggesting to use  `margin: 0 auto;` . But that (AFAIK) prevents me to set a space between those two divs.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background:pink;
}

.top, .bottom{
  width:400px;
  display:block;
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:2px solid black;
}

.spacer{
  display:block;
  height:40px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  content:"";
  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top">TOP</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
<div>
```

this is usually how I do it:

https://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/wdLpbx

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top">TOP</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
<div>
```

basically, I create spacers that can be added anywhere I need a space.
I usually add multiple, with various dimensions

And, btw, you need to close the divs, in the code you pasted above you are not

Answer (score 0):

## What I would do

What I would do, is...

1. Use `margin : 0 auto;` to center the outer `div`
2. Add a `margin-top` to the bottom `div` or a `margin-bottom` to the top `div`.

---

### Example

```css
.outer {
   width : 50%;        /* the width of your outer block */
   margin : 0 auto;    /* to center the outer block */
   background : #f0f;  /* to demonstrate the width & height of the outer block */
}

.top, .bottom {
   background : #ff0;  /* to demonstrate the width & height of both inner blocks */
}

.bottom {
   margin-top : 10px;  /* to add a margin between top & bottom */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="top">TOP</div>
  <div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
<div>
```

---

## Alternative

Alternatively, you could also...

1. Use `margin : 0 auto;` to center the two inner `div`s
2. Add a `margin-top` to the bottom `div` or a `margin-bottom` to the top `div`.

### Example

```css
.outer {
   background : #f0f;  /* to demonstrate the width & height of the outer div*/
}

.top, .bottom {
   width : 50%;        /* the width of your inner blocks */
   margin : 0 auto;    /* to center the inner blocks */
   background : #ff0;  /* to demonstrate the width & height of inner blocks */
}

.bottom {
   margin-top : 10px;  /* to add a margin between top & bottom */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="top">TOP</div>
  <div class="bottom">BOTTOM</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this? You can add top margin to the bottom div.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top, .bottom {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
</div>
```